# What is the easiest way to get required keys from array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I required to extract unique keys from array, leaving unwanted keys. here is my try it works fine.
But looking for the easiest way.

[Live demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/rB6gMB7hJIhyM8UZ?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

```js
const data = [{
  "year": "2021",
  "europe": 5,
  "namerica": 2.5,
  "asia": 1
}, {
  "year": "2022",
  "europe": 2.6,
  "namerica": 6.7,
  "asia": 2.2
}, {
  "year": "2023",
  "europe": 4.8,
  "namerica": 1.9,
  "asia": 4.4
}];

const uniqueLables = [];
const omit = ["year"]

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data[i])) {
    if (!uniqueLables.includes(key)) {
      if (!omit.includes(key)) {
        uniqueLables.push(key);
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(uniqueLables) // => ['europe', 'namerica', 'asia']
```

Comment: That would be a question for codereview and not here.

Comment: Is there a way to switch from here?  avoiding duplicate

Comment: We will answer it anyway because it is interesting ;)

Comment: I have always wondered why CodeReviews never shows up in move section. Someone else can mark it to move there

Comment: @Rajesh, it's because these questions generally need significant edits to bring them on topic for [codereview.se]. The things that need changing are described in [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778). For example, reviewers need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *does* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; ideally the unit tests should be included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need your `omit` keys to be dynamic (ie: in an array), you can merge every object together (using `Object.assign()`) to get an object with all keys, and then extract an object excluding `year` using destructuring assignment and take the keys of that:

```js
const data = [{ "year": "2021", "europe": 5, "namerica": 2.5, "asia": 1 }, { "year": "2022", "europe": 2.6, "namerica": 6.7, "asia": 2.2 }, { "year": "2023", "europe": 4.8, "namerica": 1.9, "asia": 4.4 }];
//     v-- omit
const {year, ...r} = Object.assign({}, ...data);
const keys = Object.keys(r);
console.log(keys);
```

With an array of `omit` keys, you can replace the destructuring with `.filter()` on `Object.keys()`:

```js
const data = [{ "year": "2021", "europe": 5, "namerica": 2.5, "asia": 1 }, { "year": "2022", "europe": 2.6, "namerica": 6.7, "asia": 2.2 }, { "year": "2023", "europe": 4.8, "namerica": 1.9, "asia": 4.4 }];

const omit = ['year'];
const merged = Object.assign({}, ...data);
const keys = Object.keys(merged).filter(key => !omit.includes(key));
console.log(keys);
```

Comment: Now that is smart.

Comment: :) thank you both, yours both have the added advantage of working well with a dynamic `omit` array though

Comment: @mplungjan Only way to do it with an array would be to use `.filter()` on `Object.keys(mergedObj)` I think.

Comment: @NickParsons I just did that on mine for efficiency

Comment: Your 2nd code is now what I wanted to write, but I am ok with my version too ;) I can only vote up once

Comment: @mplungjan haha, I actually started writing my answer with the same idea that you used with `.flatMap()` and a `Set` but then the `.assign()` version came to mind :). Both should work and get the job done though

Comment: `const {year,europe, ...r} = merged; // removing year AND europe` is of course almost the same as `omit = ['year','europe']`

Comment: @NickParsons I was one Obejct.keys away from the Object.assign, so great we both skipped our first inclination to have more than one solution

Answer (score 3):

I prefer a Set with filter to a reduce here.

Note the flatMap too

Filter at the end is more efficient (thanks @Nick):

```js
const data = [{ "year": "2021", "europe": 5, "namerica": 2.5, "asia": 1 }, { "year": "2022", "europe": 2.6, "namerica": 6.7, "asia": 2.2 }, { "year": "2023", "europe": 4.8, "namerica": 1.9, "asia": 4.4 }]; 
const omit = ["year"];

const uniqueLables =  [...new Set(
    data.flatMap(item => Object.keys(item))
  )].filter(key => !omit.includes(key));

console.log(uniqueLables) // => ['europe', 'namerica', 'asia']
```

Comment: This is clean :) ! Didn't even think about using Set

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a set to collect the keys, adding every key seen while iterating `data`. Then just delete the keys in `omit`:

```js
const data = [{
  "year": "2021",
  "europe": 5,
  "namerica": 2.5,
  "asia": 1
}, {
  "year": "2022",
  "europe": 2.6,
  "namerica": 6.7,
  "asia": 2.2
}, {
  "year": "2023",
  "europe": 4.8,
  "namerica": 1.9,
  "asia": 4.4
}];

const omit = ['year']

const uniqueLabels = new Set(data.flatMap(o => Object.keys(o)))
omit.forEach(k => uniqueLabels.delete(k))

console.log([...uniqueLabels])
```

Comment: @Nick, agree. but loosing reusability

Comment: @3gwebtrain In what way?

Comment: Actually, I still prefer filter. I moved it to the end of my code and it works the same

Comment: @mplungjan yeah, I noticed you did that, and it is more efficient that way. It does have the advantage of all being in a 1-liner as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution, you could do the below:

```js
const data = [{
    "year": "2021",
    "europe": 5,
    "namerica": 2.5,
    "asia": 1
  }, {
    "year": "2022",
    "europe": 2.6,
    "namerica": 6.7,
    "asia": 2.2,
  }, {
    "year": "2023",
    "europe": 4.8, 
    "namerica": 1.9,
    "asia": 4.4,
}];
let omits = ['year'];
const result = Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...data)).filter(e => !omits.includes(e));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: `year` should not hardcoded. it may rescale

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

1. Use an object to accumulate unique keys instead of array. This will allow you to skip `uniqueLables.includes` check. You can use `Object.keys` to get list at the end
2. Use array methods for loop. This will allow you to reduce mutation.

```js
const data = [{ "year": "2021", "europe": 5, "namerica": 2.5, "asia": 1 }, { "year": "2022", "europe": 2.6, "namerica": 6.7, "asia": 2.2 }, { "year": "2023", "europe": 4.8, "namerica": 1.9,"asia": 4.4 }];

const omit = ["year"]

const temp = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (!omit.includes(key))
      acc[key] = 0;
  })
  return acc;
}, {})
const uniqueLables = Object.keys(temp);
console.log(uniqueLables)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` method to accumulate the array and `Set` to only insert unique values.

```js
const data = [{
  "year": "2021",
  "europe": 5,
  "namerica": 2.5,
  "asia": 1
}, {
  "year": "2022",
  "europe": 2.6,
  "namerica": 6.7,
  "asia": 2.2
}, {
  "year": "2023",
  "europe": 4.8, 
  "namerica": 1.9,
  "asia": 4.4
}];

const omit = ["year"]

const result = data.reduce((acc, o) => {
  let filteredKeys = Object.keys(o).filter(k => !omit.includes(k));
  return new Set([...acc, ...filteredKeys])
}, new Set())

console.log([...result])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but `Set` will show as a blank object if I didn't turn it to an array.

Comment: Why the set within a set?

Comment: @mplungjan To `reduce` the value, I need to return new `set` from the old set and `filtered keys` of the new object.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm interesting. My implementation would go like this:

```js
const data = [{
  "year": "2021",
  "europe": 5,
  "namerica": 2.5,
  "asia": 1
}, {
  "year": "2022",
  "europe": 2.6,
  "namerica": 6.7,
  "asia": 2.2
}, {
  "year": "2023",
  "europe": 4.8,
  "namerica": 1.9,
  "asia": 4.4
}];

const uniqueLabels = [];
const omit = ["year"]
//create a map of omited keys
const map = {}
omit.forEach((el) => map[el] = true)
//create map of added keys 
const keyAdded = {}
//only traverse data 
data.forEach((el) => {
   Object.entries(el).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if(!(key in map) && !(key in keyAdded)) {
       uniqueLabels.push(key) 
       keyAdded[key] = true
    }
   })
})


console.log(uniqueLabels) // => ['europe', 'namerica', 'asia']
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the method in question more correctly, because this is core js;

```js
const data = [{
    year: "2021",
    europe: 5,
    namerica: 2.5,
    asia: 1,
  },
  {
    year: "2022",
    europe: 2.6,
    namerica: 6.7,
    asia: 2.2,
  },
  {
    year: "2023",
    europe: 4.8,
    namerica: 1.9,
    asia: 4.4,
  },
];

const arr = [];
const omit = ["year"];

for (let item of data) {
  arr.push(...Object.keys(item));
}

const uniqueLables = new Set(arr);
for (let key of omit) {
  uniqueLables.delete(key);
}

console.log([...uniqueLables]);
```